# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. when importing old project into a new one

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors

After importing my completed project into another project I suddenly get this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/avior/users/users.component.html:43:79 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

43         <form [formGroup]="userForm" class="form-signin" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(selectedUser._id,this.userForm.value)">
```

My onSubmit function looks like this:

```
  onSubmit(id: string, data: User) {
      this.aviorBackend.putUser(id, data)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
                console.log('Benutzer erneuert.');
                console.log(id);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(res);
                this.selectedUser = res;
               },
               error => {
                console.log('Error while deleting user: ', error);
                        }
                );
                      }
```

My original code in the old project is fully functional, how did this go wrong?
Correct me if I wrong but this.userForm.value appears to be a number and it needs to be converted to a string?

**UPDATE**
After following the advice I still get this error:

```
    ERROR in src/app/avior/users/users.component.html:59:83 - error TS2345: Argument of 
type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

    59     <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit" (click)="deleteUserBtn(selectedUser._id)">Löschen</button>

 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**UPDATE 2**
user interface:

```
import { Role } from './role';

// was class and not interface!
export interface User {
    _id: number;
    mandator?: number;
    loginId: string;
    lastname: string;
    firstname: string;
    password: string;
    eMail: string;
    group?: string;
    role?: Role;
    active?: boolean;
    token?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onSubmit` method takes 2 parameters.

```js
onSubmit(id: string, data: User)
```

`id` you have typed as a `string`.

From the template you call `onSubmit` with:

```js
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(selectedUser._id,this.userForm.value)"
```

`selectedUser._id` is a `number`

So you get the error

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Because you're passing a number to a method that accepts a string.

### Solution

Change your `onSubmit` method to type the `id` as a `number`:

```js
onSubmit(id: number, data: User) { // changed string to number
```

---

**From your comments**

The `interface` needs to be changed to reflect the shape of your data:

```js
export interface User {
    _id: string; // this should be a string
    mandator?: number;
    loginId: string;
    lastname: string;
    firstname: string;
    password: string;
    eMail: string;
    group?: string;
    role?: Role;
    active?: boolean;
    token?: string;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the id contains alphabetic characters and hence is a string.

Comment: In other words - it's supposed to be a string.

Comment: then your interface is incorrect and that should be changed. Will update the answer